# system.diagnostics.process will not open Excel file without Excel open first

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a `VB.Net` application in which I have a general method to open documents that exist on the local drive using `system.diagnostics.process`.

```
Public Shared Function OpenFileWithProcess(ByVal lsFileNameWithPath As String, Optional ByVal lPrintOption As PrintOutputOption = PrintOutputOption.Preview)

    Try
        Select Case lPrintOption
            Case PrintOutputOption.Preview
                Dim P As System.Diagnostics.Process
                P = Process.Start(lsFileNameWithPath)
                If Not P Is Nothing Then
                    Dim handle As IntPtr = P.Handle
                    SetForegroundWindow(handle)
                End If

            Case PrintOutputOption.Print
                Dim Proc As New Process
                Proc.StartInfo.FileName = lsFileNameWithPath
                Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
                Proc.Start()
       End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        If oSQL.Key_Developer Then
            Stop
        End If
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

On some computers that have Windows8 and OFfice2010, this method will not open an Excel file without Excel being open first.  Instead it will error with "Run-Time Error 2147467259 (80004005).  An error occurred in sending the command to the application".

If Excel is open prior to the method call, then the file opens just fine.

Some additional environment info:
- VB.NET application compiled to .Net Framework 4
- Application is deployed on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1

I could trap for the error and try to start the process again using the Excel session that hangs open after the error but I'm wondering if someone can tell me or help me figure out what is going on here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Unrelated remark: Please use `Throw` instead of `Throw ex`. The latter will mess up your stack trace (by making it point to the `Throw ex` line), whereas the former will keep it intact.